# load store of another controller in extJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, store

I'm using `this.getFormWindow().down('coordsa-etpParticipacao-list').getStore().load();` to reload the information on grid, but doesn't update. If i'm try to do that on the correctly controller, then work.

Comment: Do you get an error, or simply nothing happens? If you look at the network tab in your browser's F12 developer tools, does it show a GET being executed?

Comment: Actually i'm using a method 'save', inside him there's an another method to persist the data, and i called the function before. But thanks for the answer, i'm new on ExtJS and javascript.